# Add a string at the insertion point cursor location - Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm building a calculator on python, using Tkinter, and I want to add numbers with my calculator's screen keyboard always where the cursor is (just like Ubuntu's calculator).

I've been searching a lot but I can't seem to find anything about this matter, except for the `tk.constant` `INSERT`, that doesn't work, at least the way I'm using it:

```
class MyClass
    self.string = StringVar()

    # trim...

    def addChar(self, val):
        string1=self.string.get()[:INSERT]
        string2=self.string.get()[INSERT:]
        self.string.set(string1 + val + string2)
```

Comment: What do you mean with, 'gives me errors'? What errors? You probably also want to include a better code example; see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It doesn't work (edited)

Comment: Can you post a full example that I can run? Now I first need to recreate your code to test it. See the link I posted above:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I apreciate the time you've spent on my question, but i worked a way around the problem by setting the entry (Tk.entry) instead of the string itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To insert a character or string at the insertion cursor of an Entry widget, use the `insert` method, and the index `"insert"` or the tkinter constant `INSERT` (I prefer the former):

```
self.e = tk.Entry(...)
...
self.e.insert("insert", "new text")
```